# Problem with horizontal spacing in itemize environment in beamer with xepersian package

Tags: beamer, itemize, xepersian, texlive-2019

I have a problem with itemize environment, which I did not in the past. I used to produce Persian slides with LuaLaTex in Texlive 2015. Now, I am using XePersian with XeLaTeX engine and Texlive 2019. The problem is that the horizontal spacing of subitems is the same as items, so items and subitems can not be easily distinguished from each other. 
Because of the problems of beamer compatibility with Persian, I used some codes published in Persian forums, and I am satisfied with the appearance of slides, but the itemize environment problem is still not fixed. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[t,compress,xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfont]{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{0mm} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}%Yas
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}
\defpersianfont\zar{XB Zar}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   Background Block    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newbox\@backgroundblock
\newenvironment{backgroundblock}[2]{%
    \global\setbox\@backgroundblock=\vbox\bgroup%
    \unvbox\@backgroundblock%
    \vbox to0pt\bgroup\vskip#2\hbox to0pt\bgroup\hskip#1\relax%
}{\egroup\egroup\egroup}
\addtobeamertemplate{background}{\box\@backgroundblock}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\author[نویسنده]{نویسنده}
\title[عنوان]{عنوان}
\subtitle{زیرعنوان}
\institute[]{}
\date[\today]{\today}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   Title Adjustment    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@frametitle@shadow theme\endcsname\relax

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{shadow theme}
{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip-2pt%
    \hbox{\leavevmode
        \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
        \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
        \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
        \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
            \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                \begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
                    \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
                    \rightskip0.3cm
                    \leftskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
                    \centering{\insertframetitle}%
                    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
                    \strut\par%
                    \else
                    \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
                    \fi%
                    \nointerlineskip
                    \vbox{}%
                \end{minipage}}%
            \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
            \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
            \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
                \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
                \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
                \pgfusepath{clip}
                \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
            \end{pgfpicture}
            \hskip-\paperwidth%
            \box\beamer@tempbox%
        }%
        \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
    }%
    \nointerlineskip
    \vskip-0.2pt
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
    \vskip-2pt
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   Persian Settings    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\raggedleft
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamercolbox}{left}[0pt]{\def\beamer@colbox@rs{0pt}\def\beamer@colbox@ls{#1 pluslfill}}
\makeatletter
\raggedleft

\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname
beamer@@tmpop@itemize
item@default\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname
beamer@@tmpop@itemize
subitem@default\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname
beamer@@tmpop@itemize
subsubitem@default\endcsname\relax

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize
item}{default}{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize
subitem}{default}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize
subsubitem}{default}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}

\bidi@patchcmd{\@listi}{\leftmargin}{\rightmargin}{}{}
\let\@listI\@listi
\bidi@patchcmd{\@listii}{\leftmargin}{\rightmargin}{}{}
\bidi@patchcmd{\@listiii}{\leftmargin}{\rightmargin}{}{}
\bidi@patchcmd{\beamer@enum@}{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}{}{}
\bidi@patchcmd{\@@description}{\raggedright}{\raggedleft}{}{}
\bidi@patchcmd{\@@description}{\leftmargin}{\rightmargin}{}{}

\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
    \ifnum \@itemdepth 
    >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate
        \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate
        \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate
        \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \list
    {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
    {\def\makelabel##1{%
            {%
                \hss\llap{{%
                        \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize
                            \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
                        }%
                    }%
                }
            \fi%
            \beamer@cramped%
            \raggedleft%
            \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
        }
\makeatother
\raggedleft
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       Document        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{عنوان اسلاید}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item آیتم اول
        \item آیتم دوم
        \begin{itemize}
            \item زیرآیتم اول
            \item زیرآیتم دوم
        \end{itemize}
        \item آیتم سوم
        \item آیتم چهارم
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below structure for subitem and also subsubitem:

```
\newcommand{\sitem}[1]{\setlength\itemindent{9pt} \item[{\small \color{blue}$\blacktriangleleft$}]#1\setlength\itemindent{2pt}}
\newcommand{\ssitem}[1]{\setlength\itemindent{18pt}\item[{\small \color{blue}$\blacktriangleleft$}]#1\setlength\itemindent{2pt}}
```

You have these codes:

```
\documentclass[t,compress,xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfont]{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{0mm} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}%Yas
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}
\defpersianfont\zar{XB Zar}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   Background Block    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newbox\@backgroundblock
\newenvironment{backgroundblock}[2]{%
    \global\setbox\@backgroundblock=\vbox\bgroup%
    \unvbox\@backgroundblock%
    \vbox to0pt\bgroup\vskip#2\hbox to0pt\bgroup\hskip#1\relax%
}{\egroup\egroup\egroup}
\addtobeamertemplate{background}{\box\@backgroundblock}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\author[نویسنده]{نویسنده}
\title[عنوان]{عنوان}
\subtitle{زیرعنوان}
\institute[]{}
\date[\today]{\today}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   Title Adjustment    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@frametitle@shadow theme\endcsname\relax

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{shadow theme}
{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip-2pt%
    \hbox{\leavevmode
        \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
        \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
        \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
        \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
        \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
            \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                \begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
                    \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
                    \rightskip0.3cm
                    \leftskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
                    \centering{\insertframetitle}%
                    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
                    \strut\par%
                    \else
                    \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
                    \fi%
                    \nointerlineskip
                    \vbox{}%
            \end{minipage}}%
            \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
            \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
            \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
                \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
                \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
                \pgfusepath{clip}
                \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
            \end{pgfpicture}
            \hskip-\paperwidth%
            \box\beamer@tempbox%
        }%
        \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
    }%
    \nointerlineskip
    \vskip-0.2pt
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
    \vskip-2pt
}
\makeatother

\raggedleft
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamercolbox}{left}[0pt]{\def\beamer@colbox@rs{0pt}\def\beamer@colbox@ls{#1 pluslfill}}
\makeatletter
\raggedleft
\begin{document}
\setitemize{leftmargin=-.3cm,label=\textcolor{blue}{$\blacktriangleleft$},itemsep=2pt}
\newcommand{\sitem}[1]{\setlength\itemindent{9pt} \item[{\small \color{blue}$\blacktriangleleft$}]#1\setlength\itemindent{2pt}}
\newcommand{\ssitem}[1]{\setlength\itemindent{18pt}\item[{\small \color{blue}$\blacktriangleleft$}]#1\setlength\itemindent{2pt}}
\begin{frame}{عنوان اسلاید}
\begin{itemize}\raggedleft
\item آیتم اول
\item آیتم دوم
\sitem زیر آیتم اول
\sitem زیر آیتم دوم
\ssitem زیر زیر آیتم اول
\ssitem زیر زیر آیتم دوم
\sitem زیرآیتم سوم
\sitem زیرآیتم چهارم
\item آیتم سوم
\item آیتم چهارم
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And this output:
[image]
Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

By defining a new environment for itemize.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,ptext}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\raggedleft


\makeatletter
\newenvironment{bitemize}{%
  \ifnum\@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else%
      \advance\@itemdepth\@ne%
      \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth%
      \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
      \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
      \begin{list}
        {%
            \usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
        }%
        { \leftmargin=1.75em \itemindent=0em%
            \def\makelabel##1{%
              {%  
                  \hss\llap{{%
                    \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
              }%  
            }%  
        }
        \raggedleft
  \fi
}
{
  \end{list}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body end}%
}
%
\newenvironment{bbitemize}{%
  \ifnum\@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else%
      \advance\@itemdepth\@ne%
      \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth%
      \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
      \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
      \begin{list}
        {%
            \usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
        }%
        { \leftmargin=1em \itemindent=0em%
            \def\makelabel##1{%
              {%  
                  \hss\llap{{%
                    \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
              }%  
            }%  
        }
        \raggedleft
  \fi
}
{
  \end{list}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body end}%
}
%
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@itemize item@default\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@itemize subitem@default\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname beamer@@tmpop@itemize subsubitem@default\endcsname\relax
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{default}{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subitem}{default}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subsubitem}{default}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleleft$}}
\makeatother

\title{یک اسلاید نمونه}
\author{مجتبی احمدی}

\begin{document}

\section{اسلاید نمونه}
\begin{frame}
\ptext[1]
\begin{bitemize}
\item آیتم اول
\item آیتم دوم
\begin{bbitemize}
\item زیرآیتم اول
\item زیرآیتم دوم
\end{bbitemize}
\item آیتم سوم
\item
        با تشکر از زحمات جناب دکتر وفا
\begin{center}
\texttt{http://qa.parsilatex.com/14100}
\end{center}        
    \end{bitemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`beamer-rl`](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer-rl) class which patch some internal beamer templates and commands for right to left presentation, the class use babel implicitly with the option `bidi=basic` (lualatex engine).

```
\documentclass[t,compress,xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfont]{beamer-rl}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\babelprovide[import, main]{Persian}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}

\author[نویسنده]{نویسنده}
\title[عنوان]{عنوان}
\subtitle{زیرعنوان}
\institute[]{}
\date[\today]{\today}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[default]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{عنوان اسلاید}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item آیتم اول
        \item آیتم دوم
        \begin{itemize}
            \item زیرآیتم اول
            \item زیرآیتم دوم
        \end{itemize}
        \item آیتم سوم
        \item آیتم چهارم
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But this code does not work and ends with errors. I have to use Xepersian package for Persian typesetting.

Comment: Can you add the resulting errors

Comment: `babel` package also can be used to write Persian.

Comment: "Undefined control sequence", "Missing \begin{document}", "Undefined control sequence" for \babelprovide and \babelfont and some other "Undefined control sequence" errors

Comment: I don't think your computer is using `texlive 2019`, you must make sure.

Comment: I compiled the above code with texlive 2019 and it ended with errors. By the way, I came back to texlive 2015 and my code was compiled without any errors.